# Setting environment variables from within TCL script

Tags: tcl, environment-variables

I was creating a Tcl script which will allow me to automate the installation of software. But the problem I am running into is that the software needs some environment variables set beforehand and I was wondering if its possible to set environment variables inside of the tcl script.

I was going to try `exec /bin/sh -c "source /path/to/.bash_profile` but that would create a shell script and source the variables into there and the tcl script wont pick it up then.

Can anyone give any other ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In  Tcl you have the global `env` array:

```
set ::env(foo) bar
```

And then any child process has the variable `foo` in its environment.

If you want to put environment variables in a central file (i.e. `.bash_profile`) so that other programs can source them, then it should be pretty easy to get Tcl to parse that file and set the variables in the `env` array.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking (at least for Linux and Unix-like systems), it's not possible from within a child process to alter the environment of the parent.  It's a [frequently asked question about tcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4282)

However, if you're launching some other software from within the Tcl script, you can do a couple of things, the simplest of which may be to create a shell script file which both sets environment variables and then launches your software.  Then run the shell script from within Tcl.

Comment: what if i wanted to set the environmental variable of the child process itself? So the environmental variable of the tcl script which is running

Answer (score 1):

The environment is exposed via the global `env` array in Tcl. The keys and values of the array default to the environment inherited from the parent process, any process that Tcl creates will inherit a copy of it, and code that examines the environment in the current process (including directly from C) will see the current state of it.

Picking up environment set in a shell script is quite tricky. The issue is that a `.bashrc` (for example) can do quite complex things as well as setting a bunch of environment variables. For example, it can also print out a message of the day, or conditionally take actions. But you can at least make a *reasonable* attempt by using the shell's `env` command:

```
set data [exec sh -c "source /path/to/file.sh.rc; env"]
# Now we parse with some regular expression magic
foreach {- key value} [regexp -all -inline {(?wi)^(\w+)=((?!')[^\n]+|'[^']+')$} $data] {
    set extracted_env($key) [string trim $value "'"]
}
```

It's pretty awful, and isn't *quite* right (there are things that could confuse it) but it's pretty close. The values will be populated in the `extracted_env` array by it.

I think it's easier to get people to configure things via Tcl scripts…

Comment: hmm `env` would be better than `set` to get environment variables. `set` also spits out functions and plain shell variables.